# Ajax calls on ES6; Getting un-def error

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm fairly new to ReactJS, and have been studying for less than 2 months, I was trying to recreate one of the projects I saw online, and update it to ES6 https://github.com/perborgen/YourSecondReactProject/blob/master/finished_project.html.

The problem is, I've never tried to do any calls before, like Ajax, fetch, etc. So when I started on this one, I'm getting an error that my ajax is undefined, I'm pretty sure I may have my syntax or format wrong, please kindly help me and explain as to what my errors are and how they are solved. Thank you so much!

P.S. I don't have an iTunes account so I used Tmdb api instead.

Here's what I've tried to do

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
    state = {searchResults:[]};
    showResults(response){
    this.setState({searchResults: response.results})
}

search(URL){
    ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: URL,
        success: function(response){
            this.showResults(response);
        }.bind(this)
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <SearchBox search={this.search}/>
            <Results searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class SearchBox extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <input type="text" ref="query" placeholder="Search Movies 
            Here"/>
        <input type="submit" onClick={this.makeAjax}/>
        </div>
    );
}

makeAjax(){
    var query = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value;
    var URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?
               api_key=0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&language=en-
               US&query='+query+'&page=1&include_adult=false';
    this.props.search(URL)
    }
}

class Results extends Component{

    render(){
        var resultItems = this.props.searchResults.map((result) => {
            return(
                <ResultItem key = {result.id} title={result.title}/>)
        });
        return(
            <ul>
                {resultItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

class ResultItem extends Component{

    render(){
        return <li>{this.props.trackName}</li>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use ajax function you need to install `jquery`. You can run

```
npm install -S jquery
```

to install it. After that you need to import it in your component like

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

and then modify your ajax call like

```
search = (URL) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: URL,
        success: function(response){
            this.showResults(response);
        }.bind(this);
    });
}
```

However its better to make use of other libraries like [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) that are specifically written for making API calls instead of using Jquery since apart from AJAX calls it also comes with a lot more functionalities which you don't require.

A example of Axios get request picked up from the documentation is as

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID 
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: I would also add that there are other ways of doing this in ES6 and React, most importantly Fetch (if you want to do it natively), or Get. You can also use a library like Axios. That said, you're technically correct in that if you want to use $.ajax in particular you're going to have to use jQuery.

Comment: @yoursweater, yes there are other libraries like node-fetch and axios that  can also be used in place of jquery which is obviously a better way since jquery comes with a lot of additional functionalities which are not needed

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamKhatri I'll look into Axios.